# Calculate week of a month

Tags: php, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP get number of week for month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month)

I want to get week of a month. In PHP I have date library which gives week of a year, but not the week of month. And I googled for it several times and found most of the solutions but of no help. So, can anyone please help to implement the same in php. At least give me a algorithm to implement the same.

Edit:

Refer my solution for this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6229815/512100

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month)

Comment: Refer to my solution for this on the above mentioned url by Jürgen Thelen