# Find the real number of weeks in a month

Tags: php, week-number

Should I consider the number of weeks in a month the number of mondays it contains?
Any way the final output I need is something like this:

Jan - week 1
Jan - week 2
Jan - week 3
Jan - week 4
Feb - week 5
Feb - week 6
Feb - week 7
Feb - week 8
...............

I searched but I didn't find a good answer to this question. Any help please?

Comment: number of month in a week ..... ? what's that... or do you mean number of weeks in month...?

Comment: Do you want number of weeks or number of Mondays?

Comment: more correct will be the number of weeks, the number of weeks

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month

Comment: Depends what it is you need? There is between 28 and 31 days on a month which corrosponds to 4 weeks at least and at most 4 weeks and three days. So the quick answer would be you have 4 weeks in a month (always).

Comment: @Sudhir of course I saw that, but has nothing to do with this, and in my opinion that question has the wrong title, look at descritpion of that

Comment: @Repox  yes but the best will be to have an exact calculation of weeks

Comment: @albanx That didn't really answer my question. What does 'exact calculation of weeks' mean? You wan't to know what weeks a month span over?

Comment: @Repox I just need to know the number of weeks in a standard way, ISO weeks number of a month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you ask:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2012);
    while(date('n', $timestamp) == $i)
    {
        echo date('F', $timestamp).' - Week '.  date('W', $timestamp)."<br>";
        $timestamp = strtotime("+1 week", $timestamp);
    }   
}
```

Comment: It seems to work exept for the first week of January it prints: January - Week 52

Comment: That's because the first day in January 2012 *is* week 52?

Comment: @albanx: this is the definition for week numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date