# How to find week number of a day in a month using php

Tags: php

hai i found this [PHP get number of week for month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month) quiet helpful but it makes some error on all months start on Sundays for example  "2013-09-01" gives week number as 2 (actually its '1')..
 any one got some idea?? please share thanks in advance.....

Comment: The comments on the accepted answer of that question indicate that the solution has bugs.  Have you tried the other answers?  They appear to work flawlessly.

Comment: you are right mate...i found one from them...thanx...and sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add strtotime function to it.. Works fine.. date("W",strtotime("2013-09-01"));

Comment: Doesn't this give the week number in the year? I thought the OP wanted week number of a day in a month

Answer (score 3):

use `date("W","2013-09-01");`.it will return week number as 01.

Comment: thanx but this giving me a notice message....[Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered]

Comment: I can confirm it returns the week of the year, not of the month. Bad answer

Answer (score 1):

This utility function returns the week of the month for a specific day. Needs two args: the wanted day, and the first day of the same month

```
class WeekCalculator
{    
    public static function getWeekOfMonth($date, $firstDayOfMonth) {    
        $w1 = date("W", $firstDayOfMonth->getTimestamp());
        $w2 = date("W", $date->getTimestamp());

        $weekNum = $w2 - $w1 + 1;
        return $weekNum;
    }
}
```

Example usage

```
WeekCalculator::getWeekOfMonth(new \DateTime('2016-8-8'), new \DateTime('2016-8-1'));
```

Returns 2 (second week of August 2016)