# how to get date format ( week 3 of month Jan) from week no

Tags: php

I have array of week numbers from 1 to 52. how i can convert it to

```
[week 1 jan],[week 2 jan] .......
```

using PHP

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Tip: look at [`date()`](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: I tried this with no luck
$m=date('F',strtotime('1 January 2010 +'.$record->tms.' weeks'));

Comment: There are more parameters in the manual than `F`, no? (You can use multiple ones at once)

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do?  Find the week numbers that fall into a specific month?

Comment: Here's another thread on the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try a loop, start with `1/jan`, use `DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 week');` and `DateTime::add` each time in the loop to add the next week, use `DateTime::format` to get the month also checking the current year in each iteration to make sure the loop hasn't moved to the next year.

Code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$weeks = array();
$dt = new DateTime("2013-01-01");
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString("1 week");

for($i=1; $i <= 52; $i++)
{
    $weeks[$i] = "week " . $i . " " . $dt->format("M"); 
    $dt = $dt->add($interval);
}

print_r($weeks);
```

If you want a function that will return a month abbreviation from a week:

```
function weekMonth($week)
{
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    return (new DateTime("2013-01-01"))->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString($week." week"))->format("M");
}

echo weekMonth(6);
```

Comment: Actuly I do not get your answer ..can you show it in some code?

Answer (score 0):

OK ... I fix it and here is my code

```
function getWeeks($date, $rollover)
{
    $cut = substr($date, 0, 8);
    $daylen = 86400;

    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $first = strtotime($cut . "00");
    $elapsed = ($timestamp - $first) / $daylen;

    $i = 1;
    $weeks = 1;

    for($i; $i<=$elapsed; $i++)
    {
        $dayfind = $cut . (strlen($i) < 2 ? '0' . $i : $i);
        $daytimestamp = strtotime($dayfind);

        $day = strtolower(date("l", $daytimestamp));

        if($day == strtolower($rollover))  $weeks ++;
    }

    return $weeks;
}
```

and in the foreach I added

```
$x="1/1/2013 + ".$record->tms." weeks";
$m=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($x));
$first_week_start=getWeeks($m, "sunday");
if($first_week_start == 1){$typo="st";}
if($first_week_start == 2){$typo="nd";}
if($first_week_start == 3){$typo="rd";}
if($first_week_start == 4){$typo="th";}
if($first_week_start == 5){$typo="th";}
$month=date("M", strtotime($m));
$final_format .= "'".$first_week_start.$typo ." week in ".$month."'";
```