# how to get Current Week Number of Current month in php

Tags: php, date

I need to display the date of Tuesday for this week, next week, and the week after that.

For example,

```
$first_date = date('m/d/y',strtotime('tuesday this week'));  =>result => '01/10/13'

$second_date = date('m/d/y',strtotime('tuesday next week'));  =>result => '08/10/13'

$third_date = -----This one i needed--------  =>result => '15/10/13'
```

Comment: Probably this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month

Comment: Did you mean 'd/m/y' instead of 'm/d/y'?

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the Tuesday in the third week from the current week?

Comment: actually i needed third week date from the current month

Comment: The third Tuesday in the current month?

Comment: yes... but in a month some time we have 4 tuesdays and 5 tuesdays.. once we get the total on of weeks in the current month, we can get the dates, which week we needed..

Comment: I'm sorry, you are not making any sense. You want the dates of _all_ the Tuesdays in the month?

Comment: No friend, I just need the number of Tuesdays that is the number of weeks in the current month, with which I can get the next date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$third_date = date('m/d/y',strtotime('tuesday +2 week'));
```

Online example:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd9189f69add69490cb0254c23ada04a24355338

Comment: actually it returns 10/22/13

Comment: That's because it's calculated trough the server time from today.

Answer (score 1):

The third Tuesday from Tuesday this week can be found like this:-

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setISODate($date->format('o'), $date->format('W'), 2);
$date->add(new \DateInterval('P3W'));
```

Although it isn't 100% clear that that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$third_date = date('m/d/y', strtotime($second_date . ' + 7 days'));
```

Based on the fact that $second_date is on a tuesday, then second date plus 7 days will be also on a tuesday.