# Whats the best way to work out which week it is within a month?

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to work out which number week it is within a certain month.

For example

```
Days 1 - 7 = Week 1
Days 8 - 14 = Week 2
Days 15 - 21 = Week 3
Days 22 - 28 = Week 4
```

I know there are more days in some months than 28 but that doesn't matter i only want to work out 4 weeks worth.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to consider something like Monday is the first day of the week, or should 1-7 strictly be considered the first week?

Comment: Have a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month

Comment: `ceil($day / 7)` should work: http://codepad.viper-7.com/s2LQxG

Comment: Just dates 1st to 7th are week one.

Comment: @Exoon , what is your input and expected output ?

Comment: input is date("d") and output should just be 1, 2, 3,4 i just tried the ceil($day / 7); seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a day in your hand; So basic but something like below:

```
if ($day > 0 && $day <8) {
$week = 1;
} else if ($day > 7 && $day <15) {
$week = 2;
} else if ($day > 14 && $day <22) {
$week = 3;
} else if ($day > 21 && $day <32) {
$week = 4;
}
```