# How many weeks are in each month of the year 2015 and 2016 based on ISO standard?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date-arithmetic, generate-series

This year 2014 has:

```
Jan-4
Feb-4
Mar-5
Apr-4
May-4
Jun-5
Jul-4
Aug-4
Sep-5
Oct-4
Nov-4
Dec-5
```

How to calculate this for any given year?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP get number of week for month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month)

Comment: Why not just understand the _rule_ for numbering the weeks in a year: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_year

Comment: Your question does not make sense. *The ISO standard does not define any association of weeks to months. A date is either expressed with a month and day-of-the-month, or with a week and day-of-the-week, **never a mix**.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_month

Comment: Sounds like a valid question to me. Just define more closely what "in" is supposed to mean `in How many weeks are in each month`. Also, you have "this year" twice in your sentence. Suspecting a mistake, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to define "weeks in a month" exactly. Assuming your count is defined (as your numbers indicate):

```
   How many Mondays lie in each month of the year?
```

You can generate it like that:

Simple:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM d) AS mon, COUNT(*) AS weeks
FROM   generate_series('2014-01-01'::date
                     , '2014-12-31'::date
                     , interval '1 day') d
WHERE  EXTRACT(isodow FROM d) = 1  -- only Mondays
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Fast:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM d) AS mon, COUNT(*) AS weeks
FROM   generate_series ('2014-01-01'::date  -- offset to first Monday
                      + (8 - EXTRACT(isodow FROM '2014-01-01'::date)::int)%7 
                      , '2014-12-31'::date
                      , interval '7 days') d
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Either way you get:

```
mon  weeks
1    4
2    4
3    5
4    4
5    4
6    5
7    4
8    4
9    5
10   4
11   4
12   5
```

Just replace `2014` with the year of interest in each query.

Comment: The ISO standard isn't concerned with the number of Mondays in a month. (I'm not sure whether that's what the OP is trying to get at.) The first Monday in 2014 is actually 2013-12-30, as far as ISO weeks are concerned.

Comment: @Mike: The first Monday in the *ISO* year 2014 is 2013-12-30. The first Monday in the Gregorian year (which is the common meaning of "2014") is 2014-01-06. The "number of weeks in a month" isn't defined by ISO - or by the question. I reverse engineered the most likely meaning from the given numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the ISO 8601 to a month as suggested [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_month)

```
select
    to_char(d, 'YYYY Mon') as "Month",
    case when
        extract(dow from d) in (2,3,4)
        and
        extract(day from (d + interval '1 month')::date - 1) + extract(dow from d) >= 33
        then 5
        else 4
    end as weeks
from generate_series(
    '2014-01-01'::date, '2014-12-31', '1 month'
) g (d)
;
  Month   | weeks 
----------+-------
 2014 Jan |     5
 2014 Feb |     4
 2014 Mar |     4
 2014 Apr |     4
 2014 May |     5
 2014 Jun |     4
 2014 Jul |     5
 2014 Aug |     4
 2014 Sep |     4
 2014 Oct |     5
 2014 Nov |     4
 2014 Dec |     4
```