# PHP: How to get week number in a month

Tags: php, date, web, calendar

I'm new to php and looking for snippet of week number in a month and what is the current week number in today's month. Thank you for those who will answer

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month

Answer (score 1):

I am using this.

```
<?php

function weeks($month, $year){
    $firstday = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year)); 
    $lastday = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year)); 
    $count_weeks = 1 + ceil(($lastday-7+$firstday)/7);
    return $count_weeks;
}

echo weeks(11,2016)."<br/>";

?>
```

**Result:**

```
5
```

**DEMO**

> https://eval.in/683361

Comment: if I wanted to start the first week as the first sunday of the month?

Comment: Like what? The code is fine with Sunday as the first day of the week. The same as for month.

Comment: since nov 1 is tuesday, therefore the first sunday of month must be nov 6

Comment: I have been looking around for this and I believe this is the simplest working code I could find!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Using a Simple `DateTime()` Class as shown below could do. Just change the Value of the `$anyDate` Variable to suit whatever Date you prefer and you are good to go. The `$weekNum` will be the Week Number corresponding to the provided Date (`$anyDate`)  [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/683364).

```
<?php

    $anyDate    = "2016-11-22";
    $objDT      = new DateTime($anyDate);
    $weekNum    = $objDT->format('W');     //<== RETURNS THE WEEK NUMBER OF $anyDate

    var_dump($weekNum);                    //<== YIELDS:: string '47' (length=2)
```

> On the other hand, if you are interested in the Week of the Month in the Context of the current Date (that is, ***as in: the 3rd Week of November or something similar***); you could modify your code as shown below. [Quick Test Here](https://eval.in/683369).

```
<?php
    $firstDayOfMonth    = "2016-11-01";
    $currentDate        = "2016-11-22";
    $dtCurrent          = new \DateTime($currentDate);
    $dtFirstOfMonth     = new \DateTime($firstDayOfMonth);
    $numWeeks           = 1 + ( intval($dtCurrent->format("W")) - 
                                intval($dtFirstOfMonth->format("W")));

    var_dump($numWeeks);             //<== YIELDS:: int 4    
                                     //<== 22ND IS THE 4TH WEEK IN THE MONTH OF NOVEMBER   

                                     //<== ONE CAN EQUALLY READ IT THUS: 22ND FALLS INTO 
                                     //<== WEEK NR. 4 IN THE MONTH OF NOVEMBER
```

Cheers and Good-Luck

Comment: I think what OP wanted is to count the `number of weeks` in the current month not the `week number of the year`.

Comment: Ahhhhaaa..... You might be right @Irvin.... Perhaps, one could also add that as an alternative... but ***Thanks, anyways for pointing out the probability...* ;-)**

Comment: I also have the week number of year

Comment: $date = date('Y-m-d');
   $newdate = strtotime ( 'W', strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
   $newdate = date ( 'W' , $newdate );
   echo $newdate;