# Get The Current Week of The month

Tags: php

Bellow code Return the No of Weeks in a month. how do i find The current Week number of the Month.

```
function weeks_in_month($year, $month, $start_day_of_week)
  {
    // Total number of days in the given month.
    $num_of_days = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));

    // Count the number of times it hits $start_day_of_week.
    $num_of_weeks = 0;
    for($i=1; $i<=$num_of_days; $i++)
    {
      $day_of_week = date('w', mktime(0,0,0,$month,$i,$year));
      if($day_of_week==$start_day_of_week){
        $num_of_weeks++;
        //$this->getStartAndEndDate($num_of_weeks,$month,$year);
      }

    }
    //return $week_start;
    return $num_of_weeks;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

``

```
/**
 * Returns the amount of weeks into the month a date is
 * @param $date a YYYY-MM-DD formatted date
 * @param $rollover The day on which the week rolls over
 */
function getWeeks($date, $rollover)
{
    $cut = substr($date, 0, 8);
    $daylen = 86400;

    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $first = strtotime($cut . "00");
    $elapsed = ($timestamp - $first) / $daylen;

    $weeks = 1;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $elapsed; $i++)
    {
        $dayfind = $cut . (strlen($i) < 2 ? '0' . $i : $i);
        $daytimestamp = strtotime($dayfind);

        $day = strtolower(date("l", $daytimestamp));

        if($day == strtolower($rollover))  $weeks ++;
    }

    return $weeks;
}


//
echo getWeeks("2011-06-11", "sunday"); //outputs 2, for the second week of the month
```

``

Source: [PHP get number of week for month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month)