# Laravel: Count integer value based on week of the month

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-collection

I'm trying to count integer value from JSON: https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json and got what I expected.

```
{
"date": [
"22 Jan",
"23 Jan",
"24 Jan",
"25 Jan",
....
],
"total_confirmed": [
555,
653,
941,
1434,
....
],
"total_deaths": [
17,
18,
26,
42,
....
],
"total_recovered": [
28,
30,
36,
39,
....
],
"max_value_of_total_confirmed": 272166
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
$client = new Client();$request = $client->get('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json');
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
$posts_dates = json_decode($response, true);

$confirmed_array = array();
$deaths_array = array();
$recovered_array = array();

if ( ! empty( $posts_dates ) ) {
    foreach ( $posts_dates as $country => $data )   {
        foreach ( $data as $dataKey => $dateData )    {

            $date = new \DateTime( $dateData['date'] );
            $day = $date->format( 'd M' );

            if ( !isset($confirmed_array[$day]) )  {
                $confirmed_array[$day] = 0;
            }
            $confirmed_array[$day] += $dateData['confirmed'];
        }
        foreach ( $data as $dataKey => $dateData )    {

            $date = new \DateTime( $dateData['date'] );
            $day = $date->format( 'd M' );

            if ( !isset($deaths_array[$day]) )  {
                $deaths_array[$day] = 0;
            }
            $deaths_array[$day] += $dateData['deaths'];
        }
        foreach ( $data as $dataKey => $dateData )    {

            $date = new \DateTime( $dateData['date'] );
            $day = $date->format( 'd M' );

            if ( !isset($recovered_array[$day]) )  {
                $recovered_array[$day] = 0;
            }
            $recovered_array[$day] += $dateData['recovered'];
        }
    }
}

$output = [
            "date" => array_keys($confirmed_array),
            "total_confirmed" => array_values($confirmed_array),
            "total_deaths" => array_values($deaths_array),
            "total_recovered" => array_values($recovered_array),
            "max_value_of_total_confirmed" => max($confirmed_array)
        ];

return $output;
```

What I'm trying to get is grouping those data not by date, but by week of the month (W3 Jan, W4 Jan, W1 Feb, W2 Feb, etc). Any help would be appreciated :)

Thank you.

Comment: There are quite a few methods of getting the week number from the date(have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month), so you could change the way you set `$day`

Comment: should I create a new function? I tried but got: getWeeks() {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to undefined function

Comment: `"22 Jan",
"23 Jan",
"24 Jan",
"25 Jan",` it will be `W4 Jan, W4 Jan, W4 Jan, W4 Jan`?

Comment: Not group by week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [**collection**](https://laravel.com/docs/collections). You can easily manage using the methods provided by Laravel.

#### Group By Day

```php
$client = new Client();
$request = $client->get('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json');
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
$posts_dates = json_decode($response, true);

/****** Here we go ******/
$posts_dates = collect($posts_dates)
    ->flatten(1)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        $item = collect($item);
        $date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($key);
        $key  = 'W' . $date->weekOfMonth . $date->format(' M');

        return [
            'date'            => $key,
            'total_confirmed' => $item->sum('confirmed'),
            'total_deaths'    => $item->sum('deaths'),
            'total_recovered' => $item->sum('recovered'),
        ];
    })
    ->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return collect($item)->keys()->all();
    })
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->map(function ($item) use ($key) {
            return $item[$key];
        });
    });

$posts_dates->put('max_value_of_total_confirmed', $posts_dates['total_confirmed']->max());

dd($posts_dates->toArray());
```

**Result**

```
array:5 [
  "date" => array:59 [
    0 => "W4 Jan"
    1 => "W4 Jan"
    2 => "W4 Jan"
    3 => "W4 Jan"
    4 => "W4 Jan"
    5 => "W4 Jan"
    6 => "W4 Jan"
    7 => "W5 Jan"
    8 => "W5 Jan"
    9 => "W5 Jan"
    10 => "W1 Feb"
    11 => "W1 Feb"
    12 => "W1 Feb"
    13 => "W1 Feb"
    14 => "W1 Feb"
    15 => "W1 Feb"
    16 => "W1 Feb"
    17 => "W2 Feb"
    18 => "W2 Feb"
    19 => "W2 Feb"
    20 => "W2 Feb"
    21 => "W2 Feb"
    22 => "W2 Feb"
    23 => "W2 Feb"
    24 => "W3 Feb"
    25 => "W3 Feb"
    26 => "W3 Feb"
    27 => "W3 Feb"
    28 => "W3 Feb"
    29 => "W3 Feb"
    30 => "W3 Feb"
    31 => "W4 Feb"
    32 => "W4 Feb"
    33 => "W4 Feb"
    34 => "W4 Feb"
    35 => "W4 Feb"
    36 => "W4 Feb"
    37 => "W4 Feb"
    38 => "W5 Feb"
    39 => "W1 Mar"
    40 => "W1 Mar"
    41 => "W1 Mar"
    42 => "W1 Mar"
    43 => "W1 Mar"
    44 => "W1 Mar"
    45 => "W1 Mar"
    46 => "W2 Mar"
    47 => "W2 Mar"
    48 => "W2 Mar"
    49 => "W2 Mar"
    50 => "W2 Mar"
    51 => "W2 Mar"
    52 => "W2 Mar"
    53 => "W3 Mar"
    54 => "W3 Mar"
    55 => "W3 Mar"
    56 => "W3 Mar"
    57 => "W3 Mar"
    58 => "W3 Mar"
  ]
  "total_confirmed" => array:59 [
    0 => 555
    1 => 653
    2 => 941
    3 => 1434
    4 => 2118
    5 => 2927
    6 => 5578
    7 => 6166
    8 => 8234
    9 => 9927
    10 => 12038
    11 => 16787
    12 => 19881
    13 => 23892
    14 => 27635
    15 => 30817
    16 => 34391
    17 => 37120
    18 => 40150
    19 => 42762
    20 => 44802
    21 => 45221
    22 => 60368
    23 => 66885
    24 => 69030
    25 => 71224
    26 => 73258
    27 => 75136
    28 => 75639
    29 => 76197
    30 => 76823
    31 => 78579
    32 => 78965
    33 => 79568
    34 => 80413
    35 => 81395
    36 => 82754
    37 => 84120
    38 => 86011
    39 => 88369
    40 => 90306
    41 => 92840
    42 => 95120
    43 => 97882
    44 => 101784
    45 => 105821
    46 => 109795
    47 => 113561
    48 => 118592
    49 => 125865
    50 => 128343
    51 => 145193
    52 => 156094
    53 => 167446
    54 => 181527
    55 => 197142
    56 => 214910
    57 => 242708
    58 => 272166
  ]
  "total_deaths" => array:59 [
    0 => 17
    1 => 18
    2 => 26
    3 => 42
    4 => 56
    5 => 82
    6 => 131
    7 => 133
    8 => 171
    9 => 213
    10 => 259
    11 => 362
    12 => 426
    13 => 492
    14 => 564
    15 => 634
    16 => 719
    17 => 806
    18 => 906
    19 => 1013
    20 => 1113
    21 => 1118
    22 => 1371
    23 => 1523
    24 => 1666
    25 => 1770
    26 => 1868
    27 => 2007
    28 => 2122
    29 => 2247
    30 => 2251
    31 => 2458
    32 => 2469
    33 => 2629
    34 => 2708
    35 => 2770
    36 => 2814
    37 => 2872
    38 => 2941
    39 => 2996
    40 => 3085
    41 => 3160
    42 => 3254
    43 => 3348
    44 => 3460
    45 => 3558
    46 => 3802
    47 => 3988
    48 => 4262
    49 => 4615
    50 => 4720
    51 => 5404
    52 => 5819
    53 => 6440
    54 => 7126
    55 => 7905
    56 => 8733
    57 => 9867
    58 => 11299
  ]
  "total_recovered" => array:59 [
    0 => 28
    1 => 30
    2 => 36
    3 => 39
    4 => 52
    5 => 61
    6 => 107
    7 => 126
    8 => 143
    9 => 222
    10 => 284
    11 => 472
    12 => 623
    13 => 852
    14 => 1124
    15 => 1487
    16 => 2011
    17 => 2616
    18 => 3244
    19 => 3946
    20 => 4683
    21 => 5150
    22 => 6295
    23 => 8058
    24 => 9395
    25 => 10865
    26 => 12583
    27 => 14352
    28 => 16121
    29 => 18177
    30 => 18890
    31 => 22886
    32 => 23394
    33 => 25227
    34 => 27905
    35 => 30384
    36 => 33277
    37 => 36711
    38 => 39782
    39 => 42716
    40 => 45602
    41 => 48228
    42 => 51170
    43 => 53796
    44 => 55865
    45 => 58358
    46 => 60694
    47 => 62494
    48 => 64404
    49 => 67003
    50 => 68324
    51 => 70251
    52 => 72624
    53 => 76034
    54 => 78088
    55 => 80840
    56 => 83207
    57 => 84854
    58 => 87256
  ]
  "max_value_of_total_confirmed" => 272166
]
```

#### Group By Week

```php
$client = new Client();
$request = $client->get('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json');
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
$posts_dates = json_decode($response, true);

/****** Here we go ******/
$posts_dates = collect($posts_dates)
    ->flatten(1)
    ->map(function ($item) {
        $date         = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item['date']);
        $item['week'] = 'W' . $date->weekOfMonth . $date->format(' M');

        return $item;
    })
    ->groupBy('week')
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        $item = collect($item);

        return [
            'date'            => $key,
            'total_confirmed' => $item->sum('confirmed'),
            'total_deaths'    => $item->sum('deaths'),
            'total_recovered' => $item->sum('recovered'),
        ];
    })
    ->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return collect($item)->keys()->all();
    })
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->map(function ($item) use ($key) {
            return $item[$key];
        });
    });

$posts_dates->put('max_value_of_total_confirmed', $posts_dates['total_confirmed']->max());

dd($posts_dates->toArray());
```

**Result**

```
array:5 [
  "date" => array:10 [
    0 => "W4 Jan"
    1 => "W5 Jan"
    2 => "W1 Feb"
    3 => "W2 Feb"
    4 => "W3 Feb"
    5 => "W4 Feb"
    6 => "W5 Feb"
    7 => "W1 Mar"
    8 => "W2 Mar"
    9 => "W3 Mar"
  ]
  "total_confirmed" => array:10 [
    0 => 14206
    1 => 24327
    2 => 165441
    3 => 337308
    4 => 517307
    5 => 565794
    6 => 86011
    7 => 672122
    8 => 897443
    9 => 1275899
  ]
  "total_deaths" => array:10 [
    0 => 372
    1 => 517
    2 => 3456
    3 => 7850
    4 => 13931
    5 => 18720
    6 => 2941
    7 => 22861
    8 => 32610
    9 => 51370
  ]
  "total_recovered" => array:10 [
    0 => 353
    1 => 491
    2 => 6853
    3 => 33992
    4 => 100383
    5 => 199784
    6 => 39782
    7 => 355735
    8 => 465794
    9 => 490279
  ]
  "max_value_of_total_confirmed" => 1275899
]
```

Comment: By today, the total confirmed should be 272166 (calculating the confirmed day by day). But if I used above code, the total confirmed become 1108453. The right value is 272166

Comment: @firewalls You can see the results in the answers. That's `272166`, not `1108453`.

Comment: The end result is *"max_value_of_total_confirmed" => 1275899*, this depends on how the weeks are calculated.

Comment: I mean for Group by Week, your total confirmed ini key 9 is 1275899 which is wrong.

Comment: Nigel is right. That is a count if you use group by week. You need to choose one.